# Prevent ligatures in Safari (Mavericks/iOS7) via CSS

Tags: html, ios, css, safari, ligature

Is there any possibility to prevent Safari/Mobile Safari on Mavericks/iOS7 from rendering ligatures in a Webfont? We're facing issues with not available ligatures in the font beeing displayed as white space.

We already tried using this in the CSS:

```
-webkit-font-feature-settings:"liga" 0; 
font-feature-settings:"liga" 0; 
text-rendering: optimizeSpeed;
```

But it's not working, the ligatures are still blank spaces.

Comment: Can you please show sample code (HTML+CSS) to demonstrate the problem, and specify which ligatures are the problem? I don’t think Safari uses ligatures by default, and the code posted should prevent it if it does. You could try `&zwnj;`, but the symptoms suggest that this is something different.

Comment: Safari DOES show ligatures by default now. This was one of the changes in iOS7/Mavericks

Comment: Just to add some context for @JukkaK.Korpela - We ran into this problem on a site that embeds a premium font (Serifa). The word "coffee" was displayed as "coee" on iOS7. The accepted answer fixed the issue.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

We solved this by adding

```
 -webkit-font-variant-ligatures: no-common-ligatures;
```

to the css styles. It prevents the ligatures from appearing and thus the broken symbols in the font.

Comment: Since the code in the question uses `-webkit-font-feature-settings:"liga" 0`, does this mean that this older method is no longer supported? If you look at the rules in Developer Tools, does this old rule appear as disabled/unrecognized?

Answer (score 0):

### More Recent (2018):

The one that worked for us is stated in here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/47063000/1920145

Refering to use the current state of the rule:

```
font-variant-ligatures: none;
```