# Font misalignment during pdf to html conversion using pdf2htmlEx tool

Tags: html, css, google-chrome, safari, pdf2htmlex

**FONT ISSUES WITH PDF TO HTML CONVERSION**

1. All "ti","fi","tt" characters are missing

[SAMPLE SCREENSHOT](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8EGmm.png)

2. Font overlapping issue

[SAMPLE SCREENSHOT](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NTHuM.png)

- *NOTE: I don't get this issue with firefox. Getting the above issues in chrome in safari browser*

**I AM USING**

- Using the **0.13.6** version of pdf2htmlEX
- Using the following command to convert pdf to html

> **pdf2htmlEX --split-pages 1 --zoom 3 --fit-width 920 --correct-text-visibility 1 --dest-dir $1 $2 2>&1**

**TRIED**

Using **--fallback 1** option solves all my above problems. But

1. The fallback option reduces the clarity of document.
2. Table in the page disappears rather replaced with empty space.

**DOUBTS**

> 1. Could you please explain a bit more on fallback?
> 2. I have tried the above one (using fallback). Please suggest me if you prefer a different approach to solve the above problem with fonts.

Getting the above issues with chrome and safari whereas, in Firefox it is working fine.

Comment: PS: I am facing the above problem in chrome and safari whereas in FireFox it is rending well.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The above issue occurs only in - webkit web browsers like chrome and safari - which provides support for ligatures - whereas browser like firefox does not.

> A [ligature](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Typographic_ligature) is a combination of two or more letters joined as a single
>   glyph

**​Root cause**

This issue with missing characters is due to ligature support provided by these modern browsers - let me explain how

1.The tool while converting - it converts characters to glyphs using poppler for rendering - now these browser when they come across characters like tt tf ti ff fi consider them to be ligature and searches for glyphs corresponding to tt and not t t

2.Since they do not have their corresponding glyphs - they just skip the characters and renders the rest - so, we fount the characters missing

**Could be solved by**

Disabling/ Turning-off the ligature in these browsers - embedding the css in the generating content

For more details please refer:

- [Prevent ligatures in Safari (Mavericks/iOS7) via CSS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19591746/prevent-ligatures-in-safari-mavericks-ios7-via-css)

Please correct me if I am wrong.