# Characters like `tt` , `ti`, `ff` in my html page disappears while viewing with chrome and safari

Tags: html, css, google-chrome, user-interface, safari

In a particular html file all "ti","fi","tt" characters are missing while viewing (The characters are there when we view it in `inspect element`).

eg: "Solution" is miss spelt "soluon".

[Sample screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SYmSt.png)

The same html works well with FireFox. The above issue reproduces in Chrome and Safari.

> **Version**
>
> 1. Chrome version : Version 50.0.2661.94 (64-bit)
> 2. Safari version : Version 9.0 (11601.1.56)

Kindly help me to sort this out.

Comment: That's pretty flippin' hilarious. It seems Chrome and Safari are trying to render ligatures and giving up when it fails.

Comment: Yeah the same.. but how can we overcome this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The above issue occurs only in - webkit web browsers like chrome and safari - which provides support for ligatures - whereas browser like firefox does not.

> A [ligature](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Typographic_ligature) is a combination of two or more letters joined as a single
>   glyph

**​Root cause**

This issue with missing characters is due to ligature support provided by these modern browsers - let me explain how

1.The tool while converting - it converts characters to glyphs using poppler for rendering - now these browser when they come across characters like tt tf ti ff fi consider them to be ligature and searches for glyphs corresponding to tt and not t t

2.Since they do not have their corresponding glyphs - they just skip the characters and renders the rest - so, we fount the characters missing

**Could be solved by**

Disabling/ Turning-off the ligature in these browsers - embedding the css in the generating content

For more details please refer:

- [Prevent ligatures in Safari (Mavericks/iOS7) via CSS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19591746/prevent-ligatures-in-safari-mavericks-ios7-via-css)

Please correct me if I am wrong.

Comment: Browsers don't randomly converts and try to render tt( and other combination ) as ligatures. Ligature is all about fonts, some fonts defined ligature and other don't. Maybe fonts you were using has ligature feature. You can disable liga using css though.

Comment: No what I'm trying to say is - when a font has defined ligatures - when these webkit browsers come across the characters like `tt`, `tf` consider them to be ligature and search for their corresponding glyph.