# CSS: Disable font ligatures in all browsers

Tags: css, fonts, google-font-api, ligature

As google fonts are blocked in China I had to download them and use FontSquirrel for conversion.

The problem: fi/ff/etc are ugly

I did all of the steps here [Prevent ligatures in Safari (Mavericks/iOS7) via CSS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19591746/prevent-ligatures-in-safari-mavericks-ios7-via-css) but no cigar.

How can I disable ligatures at once?
`-webkit-font-variant-ligatures: no-common-ligatures;`
Doesn't work

Comment: Google fonts are block in China! Wow!! Thanks for pointing that out. Very useful. I know that Google jQuery CDN is blocked in China, which is why I use jquery.com CDN instead, but I hadn't made the connection to Google Fonts. Thanks, again. (And sorry, I don't have an answer to your question.)

Comment: Currently, Safari Developer Tools shows `-webkit-font-variant-ligatures` as an invalid CSS selector. It recognises `font-variant-ligatures` as a valid selector, as [Andreas](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4952806/andreas) offers, but does not honour it.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Despite `no-common-ligatures` you can try values like `none`, `unset` or `no-contextual` . [See MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/font-variant-ligatures) for all possible values.

For example:

```css
:root {
  font-variant-ligatures: none;
}
```

Also it [should be supported](http://caniuse.com#search=font-variant-ligatures) in all modern browsers.

Comment: Failing in Safari 15.0 16612.1.29.41.4, 16612) on macOS 11.6. Developer Tools shows `font-variant-ligatures: none` as valid and applied, but toggling the rule has no effect. Font family 'Consolas', SFMono-Regular, Menlo, 'Droid Sans Mono', monospace.

Comment: @SJT Have you tried with the `-webkit-` prefix? Is it the same behavior (sorry I currently don't have any Safari to test with)?

Comment: Yes, see my comment on OP.

Comment: where do I put that code? Do I need to own the website hosting the page and put that in the page? Can I do that on the client side, in the browser. Where do I put that code in my browser, e.g. Firefox or Brave?

Comment: @AbhishekAnand This is CSS. If you have access to the website files, you can add it to a dedicated CSS file (e.g. styles.css) or in between `<style>...</style>` tags in a HTML file. If not, you can also inject custom CSS via a browser add-on.

Comment: thanks. the Stylus add on worked for me in Firefox.

Answer (score 37):

Essentially the same answer that [andreas](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4952806/andreas) offered, but here's the full CSS for easy reference:

```css
* {
  font-variant-ligatures: none;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Not sure why, but I found a situation when Chrome needs both properties:

```
body {
  font-variant-ligatures: none;
  font-feature-settings: "liga" 0;
}
```

If set any one of them only, ligatures won't be turned off.

Answer (score 2):

Seeing no effect in Safari from `font-variant-ligatures` (see comment on accepted answer above) have used

```css
font-feature-settings: "liga" 0;
```

which both Safari and Chrome are honouring.

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/font-feature-settings