# How to stop the browser converting numbers written in parentheses such as (1) in circled numbers ①?

Tags: html, unicode, fonts

We are using a custom font family and the numbers written in parentheses are automatically rendered into circled numbers. The fonts are imported via @font-face in css. Any suggestions on how to avoid that?

Comment: Try disabling ligatures E.g https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38926144/css-disable-font-ligatures-in-all-browsers

Answer (score 3):

The below code will fix it. Thank you.

```
* {
    font-variant-ligatures: none;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Without your having provided information about your system, code, or font file, I can only provide the following:

- attempt systematically troubleshooting, or edit in the details I mention above
- use the unicode `U+0028` or html entity `&#40;` for your left parenthesis
- use the unicode `U+0029` or html entity `&#41;` for your right parenthesis

Let us know if this helps, or provide greater detail for us to respond to.

References:

http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/0028/index.htm

http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/0029/index.htm