# Print from Browser produces "ft" and "ti" as single characters in PDF

Tags: css, browser, printing

I'm printing a document from the browser (Firefox and Chrome) and it is merging all instances of "ft" or "ti" into single special characters. This breaks machine-reading of the PDF along with copy and paste. Might there be a CSS option that can disable this kind of thing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out they're called "Ligatures"

[CSS: Disable font ligatures in all browsers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38926144/css-disable-font-ligatures-in-all-browsers)

```
font-variant-ligatures: none;
```